# Displaying 2d array repeatedly to update the changes made

Tags: c++, arrays

Im making a brick breaker game in c++;
When the user moves the base with arrow keys the output window displays the 2d array again but it takes some time to display which makes it not look proper.
Help me - tell me how i can move the base with arrow keys and display the 2d array again and again without this problem so that it looks smooth.
Its my first year in c++ and Im in school so explain it to me considering im a newbie in programming.

Comment: whats your code? whats your output?

Comment: The standard library does not provide sufficient functionality for this. You need to find another library such as ncurses if you want to stay with the command line interface or some graphics library like OpenGL, DirectX, SFML, SDL2, ....

Comment: Guys just tell me how to use the curses to display a 2d array repeatedly after clearing the screen and without that flickering ..Give me a code for that.

Comment: @Gaming4life welcome to stack overflow. This site does not work like that.

Comment: sorry but then its useless because im new to coding and i need an example of the code.I cant just grasp what you guys are trying to tell me.Btw I got the solution to the problem . I set the cursor to (0,0) before calling the output function and now its fine.I dont know whats wrong with system("cls").